# Growth Over time Value on Max Date - Value on Min Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a query that gives me the following Data, I am trying to get the Growth Over Time based on the start and End Date entered. I would like to take the Value on MaxDate - Value on Min Date for each server and Database. How would do this?

```
SName  DBName   Min Date                    MaxDate                     FileSizeGB
TW      RT      2016-01-01 18:00:01.373     NULL                        103
ERP     RT      2016-01-01 21:00:01.210     NULL                        121
VW      RT      2016-06-02 09:39:42.603     NULL                        115
TW      RT      NULL                        2016-06-05 18:00:00.960     104
VW      RT      NULL                        2016-06-05 18:00:01.017     115
ERP     RT      NULL                        2016-06-08 21:00:01.333     121
```

Here is my current query:

```
Select a.*,
SUM(FileSizeMB/1024) as GBSize
FROM DBinfo db2 INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT 
left(ServerName, len(ServerName)-1) as servername,
DatabaseName,
MIN(PollDate) as MinDate,
NULL as MaxDate
 from DBInfo db1
 Where DatabaseName IN (@dbname) AND left(ServerName, len(ServerName)-1)  IN (@servername)
 AND PollDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE()
 GROUP BY ServerName, DatabaseName
 ) a on  a.MinDate = db2.PollDate 
 WHERE left(db2.ServerName, len(db2.ServerName)-1) = a.servername and db2.DatabaseName = a.DatabaseName
 GROUP BY a.servername, a.DatabaseName, a.MinDate, a.MaxDate


 UNION ALL 

 Select a.*,
SUM(FileSizeMB/1024) as GBSize
FROM DBinfo db2 INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT
left(ServerName, len(ServerName)-1) as servername,
DatabaseName,
NULL as MinDate,
MAX(PollDate) as MaxDate
 from DBInfo
 Where DatabaseName IN (@dbname) AND left(ServerName, len(ServerName)-1)  IN (@servername)
 AND PollDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE()
 GROUP BY ServerName, DatabaseName
  ) a on  a.MaxDate = db2.PollDate 
 WHERE left(db2.ServerName, len(db2.ServerName)-1) = a.servername and db2.DatabaseName = a.DatabaseName
  GROUP BY a.servername, a.DatabaseName, a.MinDate, a.MaxDate
```

I feel like I have complicated this more than necessary. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
WITH DBMaxDate AS
(SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName, DatabaseName ORDER BY PollDate DESC) rwn
    FROM
        DBInfo
    WHERE
        PollDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE()
    )
WHERE 
    rwn = 1
)
, DBMinDate AS
(SELECT
    *
FROM
    (SELECT
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName, DatabaseName ORDER BY PollDate) rwn
    FROM
        DBInfo
    WHERE
        PollDate BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND GETDATE()
    )
WHERE 
    rwn = 1 
)
SELECT 
    ServerName
    ,DatabaseName
    ,mi.PollDate as MinDate
    ,ma.PollDate as MaxDate
    ,ma.FileSizeMB/1024 - mi.FileSizeMB/1024 as FileSizeGB
FROM
    DBMaxDate ma
INNER JOIN
    DBMinDate mi
ON 
    ma.ServerName = mi.ServerName and ma.DatabaseName = mi.DatabaseName;
```